# Why isn't this code working without an else block to the if statement? - Python

Tags: python, if-statement

First post in here :)

So what I'm trying to achieve is,
if a character is found inside a list in **'key'** list then add the **'other'** character in that list to the variable 's'. If a character is not found inside a list, then add the **character itself** to the variable 's'.

```
message="hello !"
s=""
found=False
key=[['m', 'c'], ['u', 'e'], ['b', 'g'], ['a', 'k'], ['s', 'v'], ['h', 'x'],['i', 'z'], ['r', 'y'], ['p', 'w'], ['l', 'n'], ['o', 'j'], ['t', 'f'], ['q', 'd']]
for i in message:
    for j in key:
        if i==j[0]:
            found=True
            s+=j[1]
            break
        elif i==j[1]:
            found=True
            s+=j[0]
            break
    if not found:
        s+=i
return s
```

input:

```
hello !
```

expected output:

```
xunnj !
```

Somehow the later part(add the **character itself** to the 's' variable) does not work unless I put an else block to the first if statement.
like this,

```
if i==j[0]:
        found=True
        s+=j[1]
        break
elif i==j[1]:
        found=True
        s+=j[0]
        break
else:
        found=False
```

output without the else block:

```
xunnj
```

**I want to know why,**

```
if not found:
        s+=i
```

**does not work without an else block to the first if statement**.
Thanks.

Comment: `found` is set to `False` only once – outside the outer for loop. If you move that assignment inside the outer for loop (but before the inner one), it should work without an `else` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `found = False` every time you enter in the inner loop, otherwise it sets `found = False` only once from the outside of all the loops, which is why if at any time in the inner loop `found` become `True` then it never become `False` and remains `True` for rest of the time, and that is why it never enter into `if not found:` as `found` remains `True` always.

Your code should be like:

```
message="hello !"
s=""
# found=False 
key=[['m', 'c'], ['u', 'e'], ['b', 'g'], ['a', 'k'], ['s', 'v'], ['h', 'x'],['i', 'z'], ['r', 'y'], ['p', 'w'], ['l', 'n'], ['o', 'j'], ['t', 'f'], ['q', 'd']]
for i in message:
    found=False  # use found here, cause you need to give `found = False` every time you enter in the inner loop, as in the inner loop you are considering found every time, so you need to set it from the outer loop
    for j in key:
        if i==j[0]:
            found=True
            s+=j[1]
            break
        elif i==j[1]:
            found=True
            s+=j[0]
            break
    if not found:
        s+=i
print(s) # you may be want to print the `s` rather return
```

Output :

```
xunnj !
```

Comment: Thanks! I get it now

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler using a `dict`, and `dict`s are easy to create given a list of iterables like `key` is.

```
>>> d = dict(key)
>>> d.update(map(reversed, key))
>>> ''.join(d.get(x, x) for x in message)
'xunnj !'
```

Comment: Expected output is 'xunnj !' not 'xennj !'. In this case key and value both should be able to receive. So I don't see how I can use a dictionary here.

Comment: Oh, I missed the bidirectional use of the key. That's easy to fix.